# .htaccess in a subdirectory doesn't works behind rewriterule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

On my server (Apache 2.2) i have this structure:

```
/.htaccess
/cache/test-uri/.htaccess
/cache/test-uri/index.html
```

the htaccess on the root `/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html%" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/cache/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
```

the htaccess on the subdirectory `/cache/test-uri/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Test "Test OK"
</IfModule>
```

the `/cache/test-uri/index.html` content is:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>Test OK</body>
</html>
```

if I open in the browser `http://example.com/test-uri/` I see `Test OK` in the response content but not in the response headers, this means than the `.htaccess` on the root works but the `.htaccess` in the `/cache/test-uri/` folder doesn't work.

If I open in the browser `http://example.com/cache/test-uri/` I see `Test OK` in the response content and in the response headers as expected. This means that the `.htaccess` in the `/cache/test-uri/` folder works (if called directly and not behind rewrite rule).

The question is: **.htaccess doesn't works when behind a rewrite rule?**

Comment: on Apache 2.4 this scenario seem to work. Internally redirected path really affect upper level htaccess.

Comment: Is this an isolated test case? Any other directives or `.htaccess` files? Is `/test-uri` a physical directory off the root, or is the request URL entirely virtual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, this should work (tested both Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.4). However, you do have an error in your *TestString* that will always result in a failed match:

> ```
> RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html%" -f
> RewriteRule .* "/cache/%{REQUEST_URI}/index.html" [L]
> ```

The `%` at the end of the `RewriteCond` *TestString* is a literal `%`, so this condition will always fail.

Also, the `REQUEST_URI` server variable always starts with a slash, so you shouldn't include an additional slash in the *TestString* and `RewriteRule` *substitution*, otherwise you end up with a double slash (`//`). Whilst Apache reduces multiple slashes in order to route the request, these double slashes are still present in several server variables (and on the internal request) so this can still break some scripts if they are not expected.

Personally, in `.htaccess`, I would use a backreference to the `RewriteRule` *pattern* and keep the slashes. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) /cache/$1/index.html [L]
```